# Overlay image with parts of another image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, overlays

I have the following image

[image]

Is there some way for me in Tikz, to remove the part to the right of the white line, and insert it with a slide of another image? Ideally I should be able to select 0-1 how far the image is to the right.

For instance with the following image,

[image]

the result could look like this

[image]

Sorry for no MWE, as I am very unsure where to start. Any help getting started would be much appreciated.

#### EDIT:

Thanks to Ignasis I was able to produce an MWE. The result looks like this

[image]

#### Improvements / Things I was not able to fix myself

- I was not able to include my original `8pyV9.jpg` as this kept
  throwing me an `Package graphics Error: Division by 0.?`. Why? I tried to change the filename, alas nothing helped.
- Why is there a white margin on the bottom and to the right of the images? I would like them to be flush with the page borders.
- Is there a way to make sure the blue image fits the pagewidth, where the white line is correctly placed? I was able to set it correctly manually now, but if I change the page borders, it throws everything off.
- Is it possible to move the right image right and left to choose which parts is included?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[b5paper,lmargin=25mm, rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm, bmargin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,calc}
 \definecolor{main}{HTML}{003349}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newgeometry{margin=0pt}

\def\mygraphic{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Q7xB7.png}}
\newlength\graphicheight
\setlength\graphicheight{\heightof{\mygraphic}}

\vspace*{\fill}\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %
    \begin{scope}
        \path[clip] (18,0)--++(180:6.7cm)--++(70:\graphicheight)-|cycle;
        \node[anchor=south east] at (18,0) {\includegraphics[height=\graphicheight]{uniwallpaper.jpeg}};
        % \fill[color=main,opacity=0.8] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\graphicheight);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \path[clip] (0,0)--++(0:11.2cm)--++(70:\graphicheight)-|cycle;
        \node[anchor=south west] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Q7xB7.png}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Simply set a clipping path and then insert the second picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very similar to the other two answers with the main difference being that I [install a local coordinate system on the pic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/194703) to make things more convenient. You still need to find out the coordinates by looking, but now the clip path becomes

```
\clip (0.6345,0) -- (0.963,1) -| (1,0) -- cycle;
```

where the coordinates are such that `(0,0)` is the lower left and `(1,1)` the upper right corner of the "reference" picture. This way you do not have to put in explicit dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[b5paper,lmargin=25mm, rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm, bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west}]
 \node (X) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{picA}};
 \begin{scope}[x={(X.south east)},y={(X.north west)}]
  \begin{scope}
   \clip (0.6345,0) -- (0.963,1) -| (1,0) -- cycle;
   \path let \p1=(X.north east) in (0,0) 
   node{\includegraphics[width=\x1,height=\y1]{picB}};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Schödinger's cat This seems very close! Is there a way to move the triangle image more to the right?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar The position of the triangle is specified in `\clip (0.6345,0) -- (0.963,1) -| (1,0) -- cycle;`, which says that the lower left point is at 63.45% of the width and the upper point at 96.3% of the width. If you increase these x coordinates, the triangle will move right. (I adjusted these values to match the white line in your image.)

Comment: English is hard! The placement of the white line is perfect. I wonder if it is possible to move the underlying image like so https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSTfh.png

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Sure. Just replace `\path let \p1=(X.north east) in (0,0) 
   node{\includegraphics[width=\x1,height=\y1]{picB}};` by `\path let \p1=(X.north east) in (0.1,0) 
   node{\includegraphics[width=\x1,height=\y1]{picB}};`, i.e. increase the x position of the second picture. (I am on a different machine now, so I can't tell if `0.1` is a good choice, but you need to increase the x value of the coordinate.)

Comment: Yes, yes. I was able to figure this out right after asking. I can adjust the values myself. I am creating a package where the user is given the options to add images and move them. My images are just for examples =)

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Ulrike's comment, here is a quick and dirty example on how to clip an external image that is directly taken from the pgf manual

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[path image/.style={
path picture={
\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{#1}
};}}]
\draw [path image=example-image-b,thick](0,1) -- (0,3) -- (1.5, 1.5) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then you can superimpose two images, once having clipped one.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another solution clipping images included as nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (0,0)--++(0:3.5cm)--++(75:3cm)-|cycle;
\node[anchor=south west] {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{Q7xB7}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (6,0)--++(180:2.3cm)--++(75:3cm)-|cycle;
\node[anchor=south east] at (6,0) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{8pyV9}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

If you want to cover some part of the page with this picture, it's better to use absolut positioning, which can be done with `remember picture` and `overlay` options and using the `current page` node. You need to compile twice before getting the correct result.

The white space around the figure was due to `inner sep` which keeps a certain distance between node contents and border. With `inner sep=0pt`, there is no space.

Finally you can use `bb` ("bounding box") option from `graphicx` package to select which part of the included figure is shown: `bb=0 0 1400 702` means take the rectangle from (0,0) to (1400,702) points (Postscript points not pixels). I think you'll have to test to find the desired fragment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[b5paper, lmargin=25mm, rmargin=25mm, tmargin=27mm, bmargin=30mm]{geometry}

%\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,calc}
\usepackage{calc}
\definecolor{main}{HTML}{003349}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\mygraphic{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Q7xB7.png}}
\newlength\graphicheight
\setlength\graphicheight{\heightof{\mygraphic}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    %
    \begin{scope}
        \path[clip] (current page.south west)--++(0:10.8cm)--++(70:\graphicheight)-|cycle;
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west) {\mygraphic};
    \end{scope}%
    \begin{scope}
        \path[clip] (current page.south east)--++(180:6.7cm)--++(70:\graphicheight)-|cycle;
        \node[anchor=south east, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[height=\graphicheight, bb=0 0 1400 702, clip]{8pyV9}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems close, but it still seems I have to manually set the dimensions. What I really want is the deep blue to fill the bottom of the page, and then stretch or shrink the other half to fit the space. Here is what I have so far https://i.imgur.com/3OqC3HJ.png. I can add an MWE in the first post or create a new question.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Please, take a look at updated answer. I hope it's better now.